# Issue: Static Text Field becomes Dynamic

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

In the Flash IDE I've created a Button. It has an up, over, down and hit frame.

In the "over" frame there is a tooltip that appears, which is part of the button.

The tooltip has two textfields in it (classic text). One is static and contains a description of what the button does, the other is dynamic and shows the "action point" cost the user must pay to make use of the button.

To change the value of the dynamic text field, which cannot be addressed normally because it's on a different frame I'm using the following code:

```
var t_Container:DisplayObjectContainer = a_SimpleButton.overState as DisplayObjectContainer;
for( var i:uint = 0; i < t_Container.numChildren; i++ )
{
    if ( t_Container.getChildAt( i ) is TextField )
    {
        if ( ( t_Container.getChildAt( i ) as TextField ).type == "dynamic" )   { return t_Container.getChildAt( i ) as TextField;  }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm looping through all children until I find the dynamic text field.

I've multiple such buttons. And for most of them it works fine. The return doesn't trigger on the static text. However for a select few the return does trigger and breakpoints show that what is defined the Flash IDE as a static text field is actually a dynamic text field at runtime.

Any idea of how that can happen?

Comment: can you give your dynamic text an instance name and access it like that ? also, it's easier if your dynamic text is present on all frames/states, even though not visible

Comment: My dynamic text field has an instance name, but the whole reason I'm using the code mentioned above is because apparently it's impossible to address it using that name even if I try to access it through the specific state or when I make sure it exists on every frame/state. It's some kind of limitation in the SimpleButton class.

Comment: I'm now using a workaround (feels like a hack on which was already a hack). Instead of looking for .type == "dynamic", I'm now looking for .text.charAt(0) == "$". And I made sure all dynamic text fields start with a $ symbol. I can then in the constructor of my menu save references to all these textfields before changing their content to something sensible. For now this suffices, but doesn't solve the initial bug where some static text fields for some reason become dynamic.

Comment: If you mean you work with SimpleButton then don't, they are not meant to do that. Use MovieClip instead.

Comment: @paul BotMaster's advice is good, you shouldn't need so many hacks. Personally I'd create the whole thing in plain actionscript without using the timeline, but if you need a custom design and the timeline, I'd recommend something like this: create your button as a MovieClip as BotMaster advises, label timeline with frames such as up/over/down/hit(if needed), add stop() actions as needed and export this MovieClip for actionscript. You can then use the assets in this movie clip and add your own functionality using the OOP method you prefer: either extending or using composition.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Next time I run into issues or have time for a refactor, I'll definitely pick that up.